# Did 'liquidus' or 'liquo' mean 'abolish' and 'destroy, kill'?

Tags: etymology, russian

I was reading the etymology of the English ['liquidate'](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/78589/334589), when I read on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/liquidate#Etymology) that

> The sense "to kill, do away with" is a [semantic loan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_loan) from [Russian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_language) *[ликвиди́ровать](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C#Russian)* (likvidírovatʹ), ultimately from [Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin) *[liquidus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/liquidus#Latin)*.

The aforementioned link for the Russian etymon lists its meanings:

> 1. to [eliminate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eliminate), to [abolish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abolish)
> 2. to [dissolve](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dissolve)
> 3. to [stamp out](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stamp_out), to [do](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/do) away with, to [destroy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/destroy), to [kill](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kill) (off)
> 4. to [liquidate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/liquidate)

1. Were meanings 1 and 3 in any Latin etymon? I don't see them in [*liquidus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/liquidus#Latin) on Wiktionary or *liquo* from the Oxford Latin Dictionary (2012 2 ed):

> [image]

2. If I'm correct, then how did  meanings 1 and 3 arise in Russian?

I know that live humans can be killed by [dissolving them in acid](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/france/11793116/French-students-tried-to-dissolve-body-of-murder-victim-in-acid.html), but this method of killing appears too uncommon (I hope!), unethical and frightful to beget this semantic shift?

Answer (score 2):

As to your first question: I can't find anything in Lewis & Short either. If both the Oxford Latin Dictionary and Lewis & Short have nothing close to that sense for any word related to liquid (*liquo, liqueo, liquor, liquidus, liquido*), then it seems the origin must indeed lie elsewhere. The closest I found was a secondary sense of the verb *[liquor](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=liquor%232&filter=CUTF8)*, but it's still not close enough by far:

> II. Trop., *to melt or waste away*: "ilico res foras labitur, liquitur", Plaut. Trin. 2, 1, 17: "in partem pejorem liquitur aetas", Lucr. 2, 1132: per poli liquentis axem, Prud. στεφ. 1, 88.

Comment: So you'd say that the meaning "abolish" or similar is probably a Slavic invention?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta♦: Since the Oxford English Dictionary says so (see the info from the Question) and it does not come from Latin, that's probably the case!

Comment: @Cerberus Thank you both. Any input on question 2?

Comment: @Antinatalist: I'm afraid I know nothing about Russian. You could ask on the Russian Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

The Russian usage may be influenced by the German term *liquidieren* in the economical sense "to sell all commodities of an enterprise and shut it down", mostly but not necessarily in the case of bancruptcy. Metaphorically, money is a liquid, and the commodities are solids.

German *liquidieren* also has the meaning (attested since the 16th century) "to cash in", see https://drw-www.adw.uni-heidelberg.de/drw-cgi/zeige?index=lemmata&term=liquidieren

Comment: Hmm the English is also attested from the 16th century in an economical sense.

Comment: Trade is international, after all. But for Russian in the 19th century or earlier, a German influence is more plausible than an English one.

Comment: Yes. But, if it was already an internationally used term, I think it makes the most sense to emphasise that aspect.

Comment: My sources just don't give the international relations. For trade terms at that time, an Italian origin is plausible, but alas, where to look that up ... (wiktionary is not exact enough at this moment to say something definite)

Comment: Yes, or just from Latin!